# CSS text-decoration issue

Tags: css

I have a text box that has been hyper-linked and the problem is I'm trying to remove the underline from the hyper-link text.

The `text-decoration:none;` setting should remove it, but it doesn't seem to work.

How can I remove this underline from the hyperlinked text?

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<a href=""><div class = "i6">Test Page</div></a>
```

**CSS:**

```
.i6 {
  height:30px; 
  width:80px;
  position:absolute;
  left:1150px;
  top:10px;
  font-family: Lucida Sans;font-size:15px; 
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color:#C1DAD4; 
  margin:10px;
  list-style:none;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:0px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  padding-right:2px;
  padding-left:0px;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: Also, you should have your inline elements inside block elements. Anchor inside div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply `text-decoration:none;`  to the link itself, not the inner `div.`

For example, you could give the link itself a class, e.g:

```
<a href="" class="theLink"><div class = "i6">Test Page</div></a>
```

Then in your CSS, you could target the link itself:

```
.theLink {
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

**Here's a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2RjXM/).**

Comment: How does this need any more explanation? It's about as simple as it gets

Comment: @donkeyboy72 I'm not a web developer :P I'm just a university student

Comment: kewl , ,i guess your second year